# Dissimilarity between rows of two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I want to calculate Bray-Curtis distance for each pair of rows of two matrices.

So far, I have a `for-loop` but the solution is not optimal at all.

Here is an example of what I want to perform:

```
a <- matrix(runif(30), 3, 10)
b <- matrix(runif(30), 3, 10)
library(vegan)

d <- data.frame("bray" = 0)

for (i in 1:nrow(a)){
  d[i, "bray"] <- vegdist(rbind(a[i, ], b[i, ]), method = "bray")
}
```

Is there a fast way to achieve this operation ?

Comment: You could look at non-for loop solutions like the `map` functions in the library `purrr` but already you'll see a massive improvement when you dimension d correctly... so `d <- data.frame(bray=rep(0,nrow(a)))`. That way it doesn't open up more and more each time

Answer (score 0):

You might get some improvements using a apply function such as *lapply*

```
require(dplyr)
require(vegan)

a <- matrix(runif(30), 30000, 10)
b <- matrix(runif(30), 30000, 10)

system.time(
  TMP <- bind_rows(lapply(1:nrow(a),function(y){data.frame(Bray=as.numeric(vegdist(x=rbind(a[y, ], b[y, ]),method="bray")))}))

)

  user  system elapsed 
  5.124   0.000   5.126 

d <- data.frame("bray" = 0)
system.time(
  for (i in 1:nrow(a)){
    d[i, "bray"] <- vegdist(rbind(a[i, ], b[i, ]), method = "bray")
  }
)

 user  system elapsed
 12.588   0.000  12.590
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively faster solution:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(vegan)
a <- matrix(runif(30), 3, 10)
b <- matrix(runif(30), 3, 10)

f1 <- function(a,b){
    m <- matrix(0, nrow(a)*2, ncol(a))
    m[c(T,F),] <- a
    m[c(F,T),] <- b
    v <- as.matrix(vegdist(m, method = "bray"))
    data.frame(bray=diag(v[-1,])[c(T,F)])
}
f2 <- function(a,b){
    d <- data.frame("bray" = 0)
    for (i in 1:nrow(a))
        d[i, "bray"] <- vegdist(rbind(a[i, ], b[i, ]), method = "bray")
    d
}

all.equal(f1(a,b), f2(a,b))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(f1(a,b), f2(a,b))

# Unit: microseconds
     # expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 # f1(a, b) 422.597 441.8445 474.2917 452.3235 487.611  744.248   100
 # f2(a, b) 835.782 855.4590 916.9314 873.6370 942.715 1303.718   100
```